# Loading serialized object

Tags: java, serialization

I am beginning java, and started to play with serialization. I wonder if there is any way to write the deserialization function inside the class itself. Let me clarify what I mean: I can deserialize an object (i.e. from class `Person`) from within another class and it works:

```
public class Dummy{
    ...
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ...
        Person father = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream load = new FileInputStream(saved_file);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(load);
            indiv = (Person) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            load.close();
        } catch (...) { ... }
     }
 }
```

But, for being tidy, is it possible to move this inside the Person class as a function? For instance, to do something like this:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    private boolean isOrphan = false;
    private Person parent;
    ...

    public void load(File saved_file) {
        try {
            FileInputStream load = new FileInputStream(saved_file);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(load);
            this = (Person) in.readObject(); // Error: cannot assign a value to final variabl this
            in.close();
            load.close();
         } catch (...) { ... }
     }
}
```

And then in the other class just call this:

```
public class Dummy{
    ...
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ...
        Person father = null;
        father.load(saved_file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call an instance method on an instance that doesn't exist yet. Even if your code could compile, you would get a `NullPointerException` because youùre calling a method on `null`.

Make your method static and make it return the deserialized instance. More generally, `this` is not a variable that you can assign, it's an immutable reference to an object.

```
public static Person load(File saved_file) {
    try (FileInputStream load = new FileInputStream(saved_file);
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(load)) {
        return (Person) in.readObject();
     } catch (...) { ... }
 }

public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person father = Person.load(saved_file);
    }
}
```

PS: I also added *try-catch with resources* instead of explicit `close()` because it's safer.

Comment: thanks! Is it also recommended to do "try-catch with resources'' when serializing?

Comment: It is recommended whenever you do anything with IO, or another `Closeable/AutoCloseable`. What it does is making sure that all the resources that are declared inside the `try (this_part) { not_this_one }` will always be closed no matter what happens. For example in your code if an exception was thrown inside the `try` block before you close the file, then you would never close it. You could fix your code by moving the close operations to a `finally` block but it's more verbose and you could forget to do it while *try-catch with resources* does everything for you if you use it correctly.